# GLKTextureLoader cubemap fails with GLError 1281

Tags: ios, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

Dear programmers and OpenGL hackers,

I have a cubemap with 6 textures ordered as written in the GLKTextureLoader documentation.

When calling *[GLKTextureLoader cubeMapWithContentsOfFiles:options:error:]* with my array of file paths, **GLKTextureInfo** returns an error with key **OpenGL error** and value **1281**.

I've tried npot and pot textures. The textures i am using are uploaded to my webspace [www.stefanpopp.de/cubemap](http://www.stefanpopp.de/cubemap/)

Here is my current code snippet. I already tried to load a single texture before the cubemap as usual and it worked fine.

**Broken code**

```
- (BOOL)loadTextures
{
// make sure EAGL context is active
[EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

/*
 Array of textures sorted as written in apple documentation
 Right(+x), Left(-x), Top(+y), Bottom(-y), Front(+z), Back(-z).
 Ref: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GLkit/Reference/GLKTextureLoader_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GLKTextureLoader/cubeMapWithContentsOfFiles:options:error:
*/

NSArray *texturesArray = @[
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Right" ofType:@"png"], // +x
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Left" ofType:@"png"],  // -x
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Up" ofType:@"png"],    // +y
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Down" ofType:@"png"],  // -y
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Front" ofType:@"png"], // +z
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Back" ofType:@"png"],  // -z
];

NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                         GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft,
                         nil];

NSError *error;
// load cubemap texture with given array of file paths
self.cubemapTexture = [GLKTextureLoader cubeMapWithContentsOfFiles:texturesArray
                                                           options:options
                                                             error:&error];
// if cubemapeTexture is null, loading failed
if (nil == self.cubemapTexture) {
    NSLog(@"Failure reason: %@", error.description);
    NSLog(@"Error code: %i", error.code);
    NSLog(@"Textures: %@", texturesArray);
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error description]);
    @throw @"Can not load cubemap textures";
} else {
    NSLog(@"Loaded cubemap textures '%@'\n", self.cubemapTexture);
}
return YES;
}
```

---

**Error message output**

```
ERROR: The operation couldn’t be completed. (GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain error 8.)
Failure reason: Error Domain=GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
    (GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain error 8.)" UserInfo=0x886bee0 {
        GLKTextureLoaderGLErrorKey=1281, 
        GLKTextureLoaderErrorKey=OpenGL error
    }

Error code: 8
Error loading cubemap texture (null)
Textures: (
    "/ShortenPATH/Right.png",
    "/ShortenPATH/Left.png",
    "/ShortenPATH/Up.png",
    "/ShortenPATH/Down.png",
    "/ShortenPATH/Front.png",
    "/ShortenPATH/Back.png"
)
Error: Error Domain=GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain Code=8 
    "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
    (GLKTextureLoaderErrorDomain error 8.)" UserInfo=0x886bee0 {
        GLKTextureLoaderGLErrorKey=1281, GLKTextureLoaderErrorKey=OpenGL error
    }

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception of class '__NSCFConstantString'
terminate called throwing an exception
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could it be that the different sizes of the images are a problem ?

Comment: I am currently checking if the dimensions have to be all the same. In the pictures i've uploaded the my webspace i have 512x512 for up/down and 512x256 around left/right/back/front. Maybe this is an undocumented limitation. Will post soon my results.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I think you need for all six textures to be the same size and square for these cube maps to work correctly on the devices. They can be NPOT, but I think they have those restrictions.